Access denied while accessing COM object in GitLab pipeline
I'm trying to automate some things via GitLab pipelines for TwinCAT (PLC development tool, based on Visual Studio Shell).

I have a windows runner, trying to automate things with powershell scripts
the gitlab-runner service runs without admin rights as user GitLab-Runner

I try to get a COM object to use the Automation Interface for TwinCAT:
# ======== JOB: release library ========
release-library:
  stage: deploy
  script:

    # debug test
    - |
      $Dte = New-Object -ComObject 'TcXaeShell.DTE.15.0'

but I get this error if I execute the pipeline:
$ $Dte = New-Object -ComObject 'TcXaeShell.DTE.15.0'
New-Object : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID 
{A731B066-C381-4701-926E-AF470E987D80} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is 
denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
At line:280 char:8
+ $Dte = New-Object -ComObject 'TcXaeShell.DTE.15.0'
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-Object], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Ne 
   wObjectCommand

If I start powershell directly on the runner as user GitLab-Runner and execute the same line of code
$Dte = New-Object -ComObject 'TcXaeShell.DTE.15.0'

it works without any issues.
I identified the CLSID {A731B066-C381-4701-926E-AF470E987D80} in the registry:
ProgId TcXaeShell.DTE.15.0
LocalServer32 C:\Program Files (x86)\Beckhoff\TcXaeShell\Common7\IDE\TcXaeShell.exe
I tried to give the user all rigts for C:\Program Files (x86)\Beckhoff\TcXaeShell but nothing changed.
I testet the runner service with admin rights, and is is working.
I'm quite new to GitLab pipelines and COM objects... What is the difference between the runner environment and if I start powershell as the same user?
I would be grateful for any tips on what else I could test.
